# correct O(n log n) time complexity for multiplying two integers in C on modern x86 CPUs?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, time-complexity, multiplication

Consider the following C-Code on modern day Intel or AMD x86_64 hardware, where the datatype `int` has `32 bits`:

```c
// calc x times y for any two integers values of x and y (where the result can be stored by the int datatype)
int fastMult(int x, int y) {
    /*
     * Assuming the following operators take O(n) or O(1) time:
     * ==, <, >, &&, ||, &, |, >>, -, +, ?:
     */

    // x*0 == 0*y == 0
    if (y == 0 || x == 0) return 0;

    // (-x)(-y) == xn and (-x)y == x(-y)
    if (x < 0) return fastMult(-x, -y);

    int isNegative = y < 0; // x cannot be negative here

    // y*x is faster than x*y for bigger absolute y than x
    if (isNegative && x < -y || x < y) return fastMult(y, x);
    if (isNegative) y = -y; // handle y in a simpler way

    int res = fastMult(x, y >> 1); // called at max lb(y) times aka sizeof(y) times
    res = res + res; // one addition
    if (y & 1) res = x + res; // possible second addition

    // if y was negative, then the answer is negative
    return isNegative ? -res : res;
}
```

If we disregard the recursive step, the slowest operation in this code, besides the branches by the `if`s, would be the `+` operation.
This operation can still be executed within a single clock cycle by the CPU. So even if adding two `32 bit` integer takes basically `O(1)` time in our hardware, we should still call it `O(n)` for `bigint` operations where a `bigint` is an `int` with `n-bits`.

Having said this, the `base case` for this recursive implementation of multiplying two numbers stops at `y == 0`. The function calls itself (besides the very first times when it might switch `x` and `y` and change some signs) at max `32 times`, since it calls itself with the parameter of `y` as `y >> 1`. This operation shifts the bits by one to the left, until all the bits are 0, which, for an `32 bit int`, can be at max `y >> 32`.

Does this mean it is an `O(n log n)` algorithm for multiplying two integers together (since it would also work for `bigints` with the same time complexity).

Why `O(n log n)`?
We are doing multiple `O(1)` and `O(n)` calculations when calling this function once.
Since we call this function up to `O(log n)` times, we multiply `O(log n)` with `O(n)` and come to `O(n log n)`.
At least thats my understanding of this.

**I am unsure about that**, since all the usual methods of multiplying two integers take `O(n*n)` steps and there are only very few and complex algorithms which are faster than that, see: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multiplication_algorithm

Simpler version of this code for unsigned integers:

```c
// x * y for unsigned integers of x and y
int fastMult(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0) return 0;

    int res = fastMult(x, y >> 1);
    res <<= 1; // O(1) or O(n), doesnt matter since O(n) is below this line and 2 times O(n) is still O(n)
    if (y & 1) res += x; // O(n)

    return res;
}
```

Comment: According to the comment, you shift the `n` bits of variable `y` up to `n/8` times. Presumably the same for the following addition. Since each of those shifts/additions are O(n), that would make the whole at least O(n^2).

Comment: Where are you getting the `log n` from?  You're not doing anything `logn` times, which generally requires halving from n until you get to 1.  While a shift (>> 1) is halving a value, that's not an value that starts with `n`, its a value that is `O(2^n)`.  So it is `O(log(2^n))` which is `O(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem seems to be a confusion between `n` and `x` and `y`, which causes you to mistakenly think you're doing something log(n) times, when you are actually doing it n times.  So to be clear

- `n` is the (maximum) number of digits/bits in the numbers you are multiplying.   This is the normal value of interest for talking about the complexity of arithmetic operation
- `x` and `y` are the *values* you are mulitplying.  So each of them has up to `n` digits.

So when you recurse with a shift `y >> 1` you're halving `y`, not `n`.  This only reduces `y` by *one bit* (reducing `n` by one), so you end up recursing O(n) times, not O(log(n))

Answer (score 1):

In analysis of theoretical multiplication algorithms, usually each *digit* operation is considered to be one operation, so `res + res` is considered to be `n` operations, not `1`. Ergo, your algorithm here is indeed `O(n log n)`, when compared to those other theoretical multiplication algorithms.

It's also worth noting that *hardware* uses yet a third way of counting: what counts is transistors, so each "parallel transistor row" is an operation, so the naive carry-adder that we learn in school is n-rows, which is `O(n)` time.  Crafty algorithms can get addition down to `O(log n)` time.

Comment: isnt it doing O(log n) times O(n) operations?

Comment: i said an addition is O(n) steps, and my answer used that as in its formular to come up to O(n log n)

Comment: wdym with O(log n), in my O(n log n) algorithm, the addition is in this not as a constant O(1) BUT as the very O(n)...